# Problem on "JSON.parse" to collect an Array from local Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Im trying to save a simple array [5,2] on Local Storage and  then  collecting it .
i save it succesfully but when im trying to collect it using **"JSON.parse"** it didn't work and show me this error : 
***"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token m in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse ()
    at HTMLAnchorElement.addo"***

I trying to rewrite many code on many ways , but the same error appeared

```
numbers=new Array();
numbers.push(5);
numbers.push(2);
localStorage.setItem("items",numbers);
let data=localStorage.getItem("items");
data=JSON.parse(data);
console.log(data);
```

i except that i will had my previous array  , but i had an error .

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("items",JSON.stringify(numbers));`

Comment: How can i share it with you ?, I'm sorry im a beginner on JS

Comment: @Emeeus oooh  i forgot to conver it to string before send it to my local storage , thank you so muuch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
numbers=new Array();
numbers.push(5);
numbers.push(2);
localStorage.setItem("items",numbers);
```

If you inspect `localStorage.items` at this point, you'll see it's the string `"5,2"`

Try this instead:

```
numbers=new Array();
numbers.push(5);
numbers.push(2);
localStorage.setItem("items",JSON.stringify(numbers));
```

Comment: Thank  you , that's works perfectly now , i forgot to convert my array to string before send it to my local Storage